Why is the Rule for Drawing a Perfect Cube correct?
I didn't understand the reason for the incident between 03:05 and 03:35 of below this below video. How can the length of the left side of a right triangle and the length of the horizon line be the same, creating the "correct height"? Can you prove it with images?
https://youtu.be/LGAURGTV3v0?si=nCPTE7DC5kIvgWjr

Well, depends on what mathematical proof your after, It depends on how wide your camera angle is and how you choose to approximate the 2 point perspective. Anyway your too early to askall of your questions even if id write the answer you wouldnt understand it for a long time to come.

Thank you, but I think it would be very useful for people like me who are interested in this subject if you explain the reason for this at your convenience.

I'm sorry, but the linked video is crappy. The perfect confidence of the youtuber is based on the lack of understanding. He mixes projection scene concepts and things in the drawing quite freely (=place of the camera in the image which is shot by the camera itself). And the sight line through the diagonal of the square is only a special case. It produces finally a cube seen OK in 2 pt perspective, but only a subset of possible 2pt perspective cube images is possible.The 45 degrees angle for the diagonal line is the actual limitation, but it luckily compensates his "station point" obscurity.

(Continued) But the book snapshot in your "plan midpoint" question shows a generally valid construction method which starts from the base square of the cube. No measuring point trickery is needed, because the square is already known. Try to use this version of the book method https://i.sstatic.net/LRsJsGXd.png  The image plane is moved to the corner of the cube because then the side length of the base square can be used as cube height as is.  BTW the measuring point method to find the right height can be used here to reveal errors.

This is a late addition. The validity of the measurement of the actual side length of the base square of the cube can be tracked back to the next top view image of a sight line (a.k.a radial or visual ray) projection session where the image plane is vertical.

The image recalls how the places of the vanishing points on the horizon line can be determined beforehand. The actual target to be drawn in perspective is triangle ABC.
The places of the vanishing points on the horizon line will be the same as the markers Vab and Vbc on the image plane in relative to the "station point".
The station point in the perspective image is the marker for "what was the distance and the horizontal direction place of the observer in the projection session"
Side AC is on the image plane, so its length stays the same in the perspective image. Side AB will be shortened to length x, but the image of AC can be used as a measure bar to recall the length of AB if the original AB is not available. It's not available if the image  is constructed by using shortcuts and skipping the projection session. Or the image is a photo or it's drawn by others.
The measure bar can be constructed afterwards if the place of the station point is known i.e. the place of the observer in the projection session can be found. The construction of the measure bar starts by placing the "measurement point" MP to the horizon line. It's the same as my Vbc.
It's possible to do it right easily in your linked video because the youtuber had straight diagonal view through the base square. The station point is on the image plane normal which starts in top view from point A.
Finding the station point without the projection scene in a more general case is possible (with elementary geometry) if the 2 point perspective image of the cube or its horizontal square surface is perfect and it's possible to draw to the image the vanishing points of the square diagonals.

Thank you, the information you provided will also be useful.  By the way, I added a new comment at the bottom of the question I asked about ellipses: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/165571/how-to-draw-an-ellipse-inside-a-square-in-two-point-perspective My comment was about the drawing of the user named Theophile about the ellipse.  What do you think?

In essence, the YT video is taking the process used to "cast" a virtual shadow and applying it as a Cartesian measure for the height of the figure - and given the intent is to draw a "perfect cube" this makes a lot of sense as a methodology. When one draws a shadow from a form, the edge of the shadow line goes from where the form meets the casting plane (in this case the groundplane) and if done correctly, travels the same distance as the height of the form projected onto the casting plane in the manner shown and so does in fact make a great way to measure your final height!
It's a pretty ingenious way of reverse-engineering what all of us who studied manually-drawn architectural perspectives learned as "shadow casting" in which we already know the final heights of the forms and have to determine where the shadow lines fall to become a system for determining a nice single-unit cube.
Thanks for sharing this YT vid!
You may also find some of my previous answers around perspective drawing, architectural illustration et al to be of use:
Correct line length in perspective drawing
Name this distorted perspective drawing
Convert from 1-point to 2-point perspective
Line-based thinking
shading in technical drawings
Drawing technique and learning - book recommendations
In that last one, although mine isn't the selected answer, the list I provide of books and references is still on-point and worth a moment of your time.
Good luck on your journey.

Thank you very much for your suggestions. I found the answer to my question in the "locating the measure points" section of this website:
https://www.handprint.com/HP/WCL/perspect3.html
I recommend it to anyone who wants to benefit from it.
